# DML operations and calling of pagereference method in void method

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a requirement that i need to perform dynamic dml operations and when i have custom object registration and vf pages like login and registration And registration object with fields name,password,email.When i entered name dynamically in vf page if i entered name is existed in object it returns null if i entered name is doesn't exist in object then we need to insert the data and go to login page. 
Please check my code:

ApexClass

```
public class Registrationapex_Rum {

public String rumname{set;get;}

public String password{set;get;}

public String email{set;get;}

public list<Registartion__c> reg{set;get;}

public void search(){

reg=[select Rum_Name__c,Password__c,E_Mail__c from Registartion__c where Rum_Name__c=:rumname];

for(Registartion__c rl:reg){

if(rl.Rum_Name__c==rumname){

clear();

}else{

create();

}
}
}

public PageReference create(){

Registartion__c r=new Registartion__c();

r.Rum_Name__c=rumname;

r.Password__c=password;

r.E_Mail__c=email;

insert r;

PageReference p=new PageReference('/apex/loginpage_Rum');

return p;

}

public void clear(){

rumname=null;

password=null;

email=null;

}
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="Registrationapex_Rum">

<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock title="Registration" id="pb1">
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="Rum Name"/>
<apex:inputText value="{!rumname}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="Password"/>
<apex:inputText value="{!password}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="E-mail"/>
<apex:inputText value="{!email}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!search}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Clear" action="{!clear}" reRender="pb1"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks In Advance
Sampath

Comment: Your code is very hard to read, and it's not really clear what the concrete problem is. Could you try to make it a bit more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum change to get this to work is I think this:

```
public PageReference search() {
    Integer existingCount = [
            select count()
            from Registartion__c
            where Rum_Name__c = :rumname
            ];
    if (existingCount == 0) {
        return create();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```